# PHP – ZIP-file creation results in ZIP-file zipping itself

Tags: php, zip

The script I'm using to create a ZIP-file out of multiple files results in a *russian ZIP doll*: instead of overwriting a current ZIP-file with the same name as intended, it's zipping the existing ZIP-file plus the actual files.

The ZIP-file (always with the same name) is being created after a page update (= file-upload/deletion) in the CMS.

Although it's the CMS' syntax, I hope it's readable;

```
'file.create:after' => function ($file) {
      $page = $file->page();
      $files_to_zip = $page->files(); // array

      $parent_folder = $page->parent()->dirname(); // string
      $target_folder = $page->dirname(); // string

      $zip = new ZipArchive();

      $zip_file = "content/" . $parent_folder . "/" . $target_folder . "/somefile.zip";

      $zip->open($zip_file, (ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE));

      foreach ($files_to_zip as $file_to_zip) {
        $zip->addFile($file_to_zip->root(), basename($file_to_zip->filename()));
      }

      $zip->close();
}
```

Am I missing something concerning the *overwriting if existing* of the file?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You are including the zip archive in the `$files_to_zip` it seems

Comment: (hacky but works) you can check if the ziparchive filename is encountered in the `$file_to_zip` variable and just continue then

Comment: Added less hacky fix as answer (eta 5 min)

Comment: @YouriKoeman You were right, the `$file_to_zip` is including the already existing zip file. I thought the CMS would exclude it automatically. I solved the issue with the preset CMS selector `not()` meaning `foreach ($files_to_zip->not($files_to_zip->filterBy('extension', 'zip')) as $file_to_zip)`. Thanks again!

Comment: The CMS is _Kirby_ btw

Comment: Not familiar with kirby, but np dude! glad to help

Answer (score 0):

> AFTER "rotation" you need to call  `$file->page->files()`

You need to manually "rotate" the zip archives, or just delete it (not recomended since it can result in data loss)

```php
'file.create:after' => function ($file) {
      $page = $file->page();

      $parent_folder = $page->parent()->dirname(); // string
      $target_folder = $page->dirname(); // string

      $zip = new ZipArchive();

      $zip_file = "content/" . $parent_folder . "/" . $target_folder ."/somefile.zip";

      //delete old rotation if exists
      unlink($zip_file.'.backup');

      //rotate current zip file to '****.backup'
      rename($zip_file, $zip_file.'.backup');

      $files_to_zip = $file->page()->files(); // array

      $zip->open($zip_file, (ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE));

      foreach ($files_to_zip as $file_to_zip) {
        $zip->addFile($file_to_zip->root(), basename($file_to_zip->filename()));
      }

      $zip->close();
}
```